# type annotations for arbitrary length tuples

Tags: types, annotations, tuples, ellipsis

I want to define the type of a tuple which starts with a string and is followed by an arbitrary number of integers.

I understand that

```
x: tuple[int, ...] 
x = (1, 2, 4, 6)
```

is valid for all tuples which contain an arbitrary number of integers, including an empty tuple.

I thought that

```
y: tuple[str, int, ...]
```

should be the solution to my problem. Yet, the ellipsis is apparently replaced with `Any` by `mypy`.

Is there a way to accomplish what I have in mind?